# How do I change the colors in a scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have this data where a participants response can be either the same (right) or different (wrong) from some other data. I use the following code to plot this:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(n_items, key_resp.rt, color = (target_presence - key_resp.keys))) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(rows = vars(dat$target_ori), vars(dat$target_presence))+
    theme_bw()
```

Although `color = (target_presence - key_resp.keys)` gives different shades of blue, it isn't the desired "red = right, green = wrong" result. Anyone that can point me in the right direction to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: try `color = as.factor((target_presence - key_resp.keys))`

Comment: could you provide example data or `dput(dat)` in your case?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!